# How to *add* rules in local fail2ban filter definition?

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I have installed fail2ban as packaged by Debian on a server under my control. Since I have some failregexes from before, I'm putting those into the local filter definition file so they will be considered as well. Hence, I end up with e.g. /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf and /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.local. [This is the way it is recommended to be set up](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/FEATURE_Split_config) and it appears to be working just fine for what it is.

However, in the .local file, I'm actually *replacing* the whole list of failregexes from the .conf file. [The documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters) doesn't seem to indicate there is any other way of doing it, and to get it to work, I've simply copied the distribution-supplied .conf file to a .local file and made some additions.

It would be really nice if I can simply *amend* the list, benefiting from the work of the upstream and Debian maintainers in staying abreast of changes to the distribution-maintained log entry filter regexes.

The only real workaround I can think of is to actually create two jails, one using the distribution-provided configuration and one using my own. This would appear to have the (fairly significant) downside that they are treated as independent jails (which you'd expect with such a setup).

Surely I can't be the only one wanting to just add a few failregexes of my own to an already existing collection, with a minimum of maintenance hassle.

**Is it possible to *amend* the lists of failregex and ignoreregex within a fail2ban filter definition through a site-local or host-local file, without making any changes to the corresponding global or distribution-supplied file? If it is, then how to do it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us take a look at part of the `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` file.

```
[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf
```

So you might think you could add here: `after = sshd.local` and cause it to read such a file; any settings in it would then override those in this file.

And it works. Except you can't simply amend entries to `failregex` or any other directive; you can only replace them.

Your feeling is correct. This is definitely a shortcoming of the fail2ban configuration file formats. I'd complain to the developer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirement and posted it as an issue. The author appears to be working on it: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/867.

Once merged, it should work like this (this example is courtesy of the developer, Serg Brester):

```
# filter test.conf:
[Definition]
failregex = failure test 1 (filter.d/test.conf) <HOST>

# filter test.local:
[Definition]
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            failure test 2 (filter.d/test.local) <HOST>
```

and regexes can be added in jails in the same way...

```
# jail.local
[test3known-interp]
filter=test
enabled = true
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            failure test 3 (jail.local) <HOST>
```

for a result of:

```
$ bin/fail2ban-client -d -c config | grep addfail
['set', 'test3known-interp', 'addfailregex', 'failure test 1 (filter.d/test.conf)]
['set', 'test3known-interp', 'addfailregex', 'failure test 2 (filter.d/test.local)]
['set', 'test3known-interp', 'addfailregex', 'failure test 3 (jail.local) <HOST>']
```